# How to synchronize different shell instances

Tags: bash, unix, parallel-processing, synchronization, locking

I want to synchronize / "sequentialize" multiple instances running simultaneously of a specific shell.

*Optionally, a subset of arguments can determine if the process can be running immediately or must wait.*

To be clear :

If I run the following three commands simultaneously *(in this example `schema` and `table` option determine the lock)*:

```
loadTable --schema dev --table person --file mydata1.txt
loadTable --schema dev --table person --file mydata2.txt
loadTable --schema dev --table enterprise --file mydata3.txt
```

I want :

- the **first** and **third** commands can be run simultaneously 

  *because partial arguments are different (`schema` and `table`)*
- the **second** command must wait the end of the **first** one 

  *because partial arguments are identical (`schema` and `table`)*

For me 2 solutions :

- loadTable shell must manage a waiting queue himself.
- a parent *proxy* shell must manage it

I have some ideas, but it seems a little bit complex...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I have made a **synchronize** function.

I can now simply call at the beginning of my script (after args parsing):

```
synchronize $myTable-$mySchema
```

It does the job but we can maybe simplified it.

code :

```
function synchronize() {
    key=${1:-noKey};    
    shell_fullname=$(readlink -f $0)
    shell_basename=$(basename $shell_fullname)    
    hash=$(echo "${shell_fullname}-${key}" | md5sum | cut -b-32)
    delay=2
    pid_file=/tmp/${shell_basename}.${hash}.pid    
    current_pid=$$        

    echo "synchronize$shell_basename($key)"
    (    
        # First step : lock file         
        isUnLock=true
        echo "trying to acquire lock"
        while $isUnLock
        do
            # Wait for lock on file desciptor 200 for 10 seconds
            flock -x -w $delay 200 && isUnLock=false
            $isUnLock && echo "Waiting lock for"                   
        done

        # here : isUnLock must normally be false
        $isUnLock && echo "unable to acquire lock" # not possible for me
        $isUnLock && exit 255 # bad luck...
        $isUnLock || echo "lock OK"         

        # Second step : waiting eventual previous process
        while [ -e ${pid_file} ] && kill -0 `cat $pid_file` > /dev/null 2>&1
        do
            echo "Another process already running with process_id $(cat ${pid_file})"        
            sleep $delay
        done

        # here : previous shell stop and the current process has lock the pid_file
        echo $current_pid > ${pid_file}

        # now we can unlock the pid file and the current shell can be running alone safely
        # (just fail if somebody delete the pid_file...)        

    ) 200>$pid_file.lock # add suffix, flock seems make empty file after lock... 

}

key=$1 # construct key using args
synchronize$key
```

ligthest version

```
function synchronize() {
    key=${1:-noKey};    
    shell_fullname=$(readlink -f $0)
    shell_basename=$(basename $shell_fullname)    
    hash=$(echo "${shell_fullname}-${key}" | md5sum | cut -b-32)
    delay=10
    pid_file=/tmp/${shell_basename}.${hash}.pid    
    current_pid=$$        

    echo "synchronize $shell_basename($key) pid_file=$pid_file"
    (    
        # First step : lock file, Wait for lock on file desciptor 200
        echo "trying to acquire lock"
        flock -x 200 
        echo "lock acquired"

        # Second step : waiting eventual previous process        
        [ -s $pid_file ] && previous_pid=$(cat $pid_file) || previous_pid=00 # 00 is an impossible pid        
        [ -e /proc/${previous_pid} ] && echo "Another process already running with process_id $previous_pid"        
        while [ -e /proc/${previous_pid} ]; do sleep $delay; done

        # here : previous shell is stop and the current process has lock the pid_file        
        echo $current_pid > ${pid_file}        
        echo "current pid $current_pid is running"

        # now we can unlock the pid file and the current shell can be running several minutes      

    ) 200>$pid_file.lock # add suffix, flock seems make empty file after lock... 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify and securise a little bit the second step

*(securise => by this way it works even if `$pid_file` is delete during the previous execution)*

```
# Second step : waiting eventual previous process
previous_pid=$(cat $pid_file)
previous_pid=${previous_pid:00} # 00 is an impossible pid
while [ -e /proc/${previous_pid} ]
do
    echo "Another process already running with process_id ${previous_pid}"        
    sleep $delay
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you need to do something like this:

```
loadTable --schema dev --table person --file mydata1.txt &
loadTable --schema dev --table enterprise --file mydata3.txt &
wait %1 && loadTable --schema dev --table person --file mydata2.txt &
wait
```

In this case you will run commands 1 and 3 in parallel, then wait first command to finish and run second one. After that you wait all of them to finish

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I don't know in advance the commands launched